# How to push on new set of view controllers from one tab to another tab?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a `tabBarController` with 2 tabs. Inside each tab there is a `navigationController`. Each `navigationController` has 3 child `viewControllers`

```
                           tabBarController
                            /            \
                        tabOne          tabTwo
                         /                  \
                  NumNavController     ColorNavController
                       |                      |
                    ViewOne                ViewBlack
                       |                      |
                    ViewTwo                 ViewRed
                       |                      |
                   ViewThree               ViewPurple//(beginning)
                                              |
                                           myButton
                               //myButton pushes on ViewOne>ViewTwo>ViewThree(end)
```

I have a button inside ViewPurple and when pressed I want to push on ViewOne,ViewTwo, then ViewThree.

```
(beginning)ViewPurple > ViewOne > ViewTwo > ViewThree(end)
```

Thus from ViewThree I would push back to ViewPurple- **This is what I'm trying to achieve**

```
(beginning)ViewPurple < ViewOne < ViewTwo < ViewThree(end)
```

Inside ViewPurple I reset ColorNavController's to NumNavController's child controllers.

```
let numVCs = [viewThreeVC, viewTwoVC, viewOneVC]
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(numVCs, animated: true)
//Apple docs says to set them backwards
//The view controllers to place in the stack. The front-to-back order of the controllers in this array represents the new bottom-to-top order of the controllers in the navigation stack. Thus, the last item added to the array becomes the top item of the navigation stack
```

*The problem I'm having is once I push on ViewOne and press the back backButton instead of going to ViewPurple I end up on ViewTwo. It's caught in  weird cycle where it seems it does't know where the beginning viewController is anymore.*

```
 //I can't push back to ViewPurple
 ViewOne < ViewTwo < ViewOne < ViewTwo < ViewThree(end)
```

**Where is the problem at and how do I get back to ViewPurple?**

ViewPurple: (first way - no crash but weird cycle)

```
class ViewPurple: UIViewController {

@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton){
     self.presentNewVCs()
  }

func presentNewVCs(){
     let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let viewOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewOne") as! ViewOneController
     let viewTwoVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewTwo") as! ViewTwoController
     let viewThreeVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewThree") as! ViewThreeController

     let numVCs = [viewThreeVC, viewTwoVC, viewOneVC]
     self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(numVCs, animated: true)
  }
}
```

I also tried a second way to present the NumNavController but I kept getting an exception `'Application tried to present modally an active controller`. I made a weak ref to ViewPurple and tried to deinit it but it still crashed

ViewPurple: (second way - crash)

```
class ViewPurple: UIViewController {

weak var parent:ViewPurple!

@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton){
     self.presentNewVCs()
  }

func presentNewVCs(){

     let numNavController = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! NumNavController

     let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let viewOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewOne") as! ViewOneController
     let viewTwoVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewTwo") as! ViewTwoController
     let viewThreeVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewThree") as! ViewThreeController

     let numVCs = [viewThreeVC, viewTwoVC, viewOneVC]
     numNavController.setViewControllers(numVCs, animated: true)
     self.presentViewController(numNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  deinit{
     self.parent = nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you are inserting Three Viewcontroller at once. You tried well to explain your problem but for me its not 100% understandable. :(

Comment: @ Dheeraj D What do you mean? I want to go from the PurpleVC to One, Two, and Three. I need to walk through all three. Are you saying i didn't have to do that?

Comment: Create push segue from Purple View to ViewOne OR create Modal segue from Purple View to `NumNavController`.

Comment: You can achieve this.... i will tell you how. I have some question please answer.... because i have some confusion related to your issue.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I tried a programmatic push seque but I realized that the tabBar and the other numNavController are in the way. I'll try again.

Comment: OK.. no issue... First you tell me do you have already written logic to move OneVC -> TwoVC -> ThreeVC ?

Comment: On action of button at ViewPurple controller  Instantiate  OneVC object and pushed it. There is no need to reset Navigation controller hierarchy.

Comment: @Dheeraj D Yes the first way I have the logic works to push all three on but it does;t work to push them off correctly.

Comment: In this way you can travel back to ThreeVC to  ViewPurple

Comment: lets say you are at OneVC so my question is on what event you are pushing SecondVC and from SecondVC to ThirstVC?

Comment: @Dheeraj D I just removed ViewTwo and ViewThree and it didn't work. ViewOne got pushed on but the backButton is gone. TO answer the question you just asked -yes. If I am at OneVC I want to push on SecondVC to ThirdVC. That works fine. It's pushing back to ViewPurple is where the problem is at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132074/discussion-between-dheeraj-d-and-lance-samaria).

Comment: let viewOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewOne") as! ViewOneController 
self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewOneVC, animate:true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please update your **`buttonAction:`**

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton){ 
     let viewOneVC =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewOne") as! ViewOneController 
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewOneVC, animate:true) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot present the `NumNavController` as that is already the part of tabBarController.

when `setViewControllers` is called it completely replace the `viewcontroller` stack of the `navigationViewController` so you need to add `ViewPurple` also in the `numVCs` array and set `ViewPurple` as your root view controller.

So then, on calling `popToRootViewController` will move back to `ViewPurple`.

Comment: I tried that from the beginning. Nothing happened. I didn't include it. It never "popped"